# enviar mail, compatible con protocolo de seguridad oauth

Tags: android, android-studio

acabo de recibir un email de google informandome de que a partir del 30 de mayo del 2022 ya no estara disponible la opcion de permitir acceso a aplicaciones poco seguras en google. Por lo tanto ya no funcionara la antigua aplicacion que tenia para enviar mails desde android. He buscado por internet y he encontrado este codigo que en teoria si es compatible con el protocolo oauth2 y lo he probado. Pero si desactivo el permiso de acceso a aplicaciones poco seguras me da un error de identificacion. ¿detectais algun problema en este codigo?Este es el codigo:

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton=findViewById(R.id.button);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("mymail@gmail.com", "mipassword");
                            sender.sendMail("This is Subject",
                                    "This is Body",
                                    "mymail@gmail.com",
                                    "myothermail@gmail.com");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

GmailSender:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator{
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("error",e.toString());
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

y la clase jsseprovider:

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Tienes dos opciones: o creas una application password en gmail y la usas, o cambias totalmente la implementación y creas un login OAuth que abra el popup con el login de gmail y reciba la respuesta de la autenticación, etc

Comment: ok, ya tengo una application password, ¿hay algun codigo de ejemplo sobre como implementarla?

Comment: tengo activada la autenticacion en dos pasos y la password de la aplicacion, pero no encuentro ningun ejemplo que utilice este metodo.

Comment: Sólo tienes que usar la applicartion password como tu contraseña y el usuario es el usuario normal.

Comment: genial! funciono, muchas gracias.